# how to concatenate two array with same id using angular or javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am kind of new to angular or javascript. I am trying to append or concate the values with the same id into one row.

```
var array = [{
            id: "410",
            value: "val1"
        }, {
            id: "411",
            value: "val1"
        }, {
            id: "412",
            value: "val4"
        },{
            id: "410",
            value: "val2"];

            var output = [];
```

i want the output to be

```
output = [
{id:"410", value:["val1","val2"]},
{id:"411", value:["val1"]},
{"id":412,value:["val4"]}]
```

any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: That's not a valid output. You would need to put the values into an array or other data structure.

Comment: value is an array? i.e: `{id:"410", value:["val1","val2"]}`

Comment: Post your attempts please. SO is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `value` attribute must be an array.

You can use `reduce` function to get the desired output.

```js
var array = [{ id: "410", value: "val1" }, 
             { id: "411", value: "val1" }, 
             { id: "412", value: "val4" }, 
             { id: "410", value: "val2"}];

var output = array.reduce((a, c) => {
  var id = c.id;
  var e = a.filter((e) => e.id == id)[0];
  if (e) {
    e.value.push(c.value);
  } else {
    a = [...a, ...[{ id: id, value: [c.value] }]];
  }
  
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

## Resource

- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: thank you so much this really helped me. i changed it into complete javascript by removing spread operators.

Comment: output = array1.reduce(function (a, c) {
            console.log("trying to console a", a);
            console.log("trying to console c", c);
            var id = c.inputFileId,

                e = a.filter(function (e) {return e.id === id; })[0];
            console.log("trying e", e);
            if (e) {
                e.value.push(c.roleName);
            } else {
                a = a.concat([{ id: id, value: [c.roleName] }]);
            }
            return a;
        }, []);